# Sorting a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have this problem that I need to sort a matrix in MATLAB.

Input:

```
[20    10    0    50    0; 
 300   100   50   50    100]
```

And I'd like the output to be:

```
[0    0    10    20    50;

 50   100  100   300   50]
```

So I'd like it to sort the first column but the rows remain unchanged. Help is needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did write the answer yourself, try `sort`

```
A = [20    10    0    50    0;  300   100   50   50    100];
[A(1,:) idx] = sort(A(1,:),2);
A(2,:) = A(2,idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) and get the desired result in one line:

```
result = sortrows(A.',1).';
```